# How to set ToolTip Visibility for the Grid column using DependencyProperty inside of IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

I want to set `Visibility` for `ToolTip` (DependencyProperty) inside of `IValueConverter` using special logic. I want to show/hide `ToolTip` only when I have the special condition.

How can I do this?

```xaml
</UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:ToolTipMessageConverter x:Key="ToolTipMessageConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding DataField}">
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.ToolTipTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding OtherData,Converter={StaticResource ToolTipMessageConverter}}"  Visibility=??? />
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.ToolTipTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColum>
<telerik:RadGridView>
```

```csharp
public class ToolTipMessageConverter : FrameworkElement, IValueConverter
{
    public Visibility ToolTipVisibility
    {
        get { return (Visibility)GetValue(ToolTipVisibilityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ToolTipVisibilityProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolTipVisibilityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ToolTipVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(ToolTipMessageConverter), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var status = (string)value;
        var mess = string.Empty;
        if (status == "Available")
        {
            this.SetValue(ToolTipVisibilityProperty, Visibility.Hidden);
        }
        else
        {
            mess = "User message... " + value;
            this.SetValue(ToolTipVisibilityProperty, Visibility.Visible);
        }
        return mess;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should simply have two bindings with two converters, one for the Text property, the other for Visibility.

Comment: I don't want this solution.I want to use dependency property

Comment: That won't work.

Comment: I am looking the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it should work:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding OtherData,Converter={StaticResource ToolTipMessageConverter}}"  Visibility="{Binding ToolTipVisibility, Source={StaticResource ToolTipMessageConverter}}" />
```